# USB Short Circuit Breakdown

Tags: usb, short-circuit

First of all, apologies for posting this here, but I couldn't find any stack exchange hardware website. While plugging the headphones to my laptop it touched the USB port and I heard (through the earpiece) a plugging flicker sound. Then after a while I discovered that this USB ports along with the one next to it are not working so I guessed that they're connected in parallel. My question is : So what happened seems like a short circuit to me and I know they will never work again, but what if I tried to simply change the USB cores, are they gonna work , or might that be an irreversible motherboard issue?

Status: Resolved.
Credits to "DoxyLover"
Solution: It was a kind of motherboard automatic protection. I had to reboot the computer, log into the boot setup, enable and disable the USB devices from the Boot Menu. Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you tried power-cycling the computer? I believe some motherboards use active protection on the USB ports that needs to be reset.

Comment: What is the model of the laptop?

Comment: @ DoxyLover you're absolutely right. Thank you very much. Rebooting didn't actually help, but I had to switch the USB ports on and off from the booting blue screen at first. Off topic voters: I thought it was a hardware failure since I work as an IT Engineer and almost all the troubleshooting including driver re-installation and other means of software troubleshooting didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my experience:

When moving to my new flat, I had no TV / internet the first days. But I had a USB TV receiver as well as a USB UMTS stick. For better signal quality and convenience, I plugged them into an USB hub, taped it all to a window, and used a 3m USB cable. However, both devices together sourced too much current for stable oberation, so I decided to search the wall wart for the hub. I found it, plugged it in, got noise, smell and a bang. It turned out it was not the 6V DC wart, but a 16V AC, 1A one... Finally, the hub, the TV receiver and several USB ports didn't work any more. The ports did not deliver 5V any more.

It turned out the laptop had special chips from TI for power supply control of the USB ports. They sit on the 5V rail of the laptop and mainly maintain the maximum of 500mA for each port (one IC for two ports). I got some of these chips, soldered them to the  mainboard, and the USB was running again.

So, if the 5V is missing on your USB port, you may try to identify ICs (or fuses) near the ports, maybe, you find something. If you damaged the data lines, you probably can't recover it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're lucky (and brave), you might find that a board-mounted fuse simply popped.  Measure the two outer pins (1 and 4) with a voltmeter, and see if you have 5V.  If not, it could well be a single component failure (a fuse or PTC resistor, for example).  Of course, it might be a burned trace instead.

If you do have power present, then you probably have a bigger failure.  Check traces, smell the IC's, all that good stuff...

Good luck!